# Changes in environment variables are not reflected in python

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, windows-10

trying to install spark, I've some problems when I try to set the system enviroment variables. I modify the PATH using:

“Advanced system settings” → “Environment Variables”

but when I call these variables from python, using the code:

```
import os
path = os.environ.get('PATH', None)
print(path)
```

The path that shows python don't have the modifications that I put. Thanks

Comment: Did you add your new path to the "Path" variable from system variables or user variables?

Answer (score 5):

Any program invoked from the command prompt will be given the environment variables that was at the time the command prompt was invoked.

Therefore, when you modify or add an environment variable you should restart the command prompt (cmd.exe) and then invoke python to see the changes.